# Which database type is /etc/aliases.db?

Tags: email, postfix, database

Which database type is `/etc/aliases.db`?
It is not SQLite, MySQL or PostgreSQL.

Comment: My Ubuntu system does not have such a file (neither another I could `ssh` into) so I can't look, but I'd ask the system for a class, ie. `file /etc/aliases.db`  (eg. `file /etc/hddtemp.db` shows it's only UTF-8 Unicode text)

Comment: file  /etc/aliases.db
/etc/aliases.db: Berkeley DB (Hash, version 9, native byte-order)

Comment: you have your answer - `file` works for almost every type of file you'll find on your system too  (it's what GNU/Linux & unix rely on instead of the 'extension')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [the Postfix Database README](http://www.postfix.org/DATABASE_README.html#types):

> **btree**
>   A sorted, balanced tree structure. This is available only on systems
>   with support for Berkeley DB databases. Database files are created
>   with the `postmap(1)` or `postalias(1)` command. The lookup table name
>   as used in "`btree:table`" is the database file name without the
>   "`.db`" suffix.
>   ...
>   **hash**
>   An indexed file type based on hashing. This is available only on
>   systems with support for Berkeley DB databases. Public database files
>   are created with the `postmap(1)` or `postalias(1)` command, and
>   private databases are maintained by Postfix daemons. The database name
>   as used in "`hash:table`" is the database file name without the
>   "`.db`" suffix.

So these are [Berkeley DB databases](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berkeley_DB), using either Btrees or hashes.